# pyspark ; how to reduce by values efficiently

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's consider the pair RDD:

```
x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 1), ("a", 4), ("c", 7)])
```

Is there a more efficient alternative to:

```
x.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduce(lambda x, y: x+y)
```

in order to find the sum of all the values

Comment: There is small difference in execution strategy between `sum` and `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)` but I doubt it will significantly affect performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `x` is a `PairRDD` you can use `values` method instead of extracting values manually:

```
x.values().sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `sum` method in the [RDD API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html)

```
x.map(lambda x: x[1]).sum()
```

> sum(self)     source code
>
> Add up the elements in this RDD.

```
sc.parallelize([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).sum()
6.0
```